# Extracting just GPS location to new files named their date stamp from one huge log file

Tags: bash, python, data

So, i've huge (over 100k records) log file, and need to extract all GPS locations based on their datestamp.

```
./production.log.109.gz:I, [2022-02-10T10:00:59.703529 #25190]  INFO -- : #<Event::TeltonikaServer:3ffcbe931d90>:357544377733734 TS: 2022-02-10 10:00:35 +0000, GPS: 52.1773033,20.8162, SAT: 17, KM/H: 0, V: 26343
./production.log.109.gz:I, [2022-02-10T10:01:13.939349 #25190]  INFO -- : #<Event::TeltonikaServer:3ffcbe931d90>:357544377733734 TS: 2022-02-10 10:00:40 +0000, GPS: 52.1773033,20.8162, SAT: 17, KM/H: 0, V: 26352
./production.log.109.gz:I, [2022-02-10T10:10:44.757308 #25190]  INFO -- : #<Event::TeltonikaServer:3ffcbe931d90>:357544377733734 TS: 2022-02-10 10:10:40 +0000, GPS: 52.1773033,20.8162, SAT: 18, KM/H: 0, V: 25924
```

So, basically, for those 3 records i need to find, that it's `10th February 2022`, cut and paste two stamps after `"GPS:"` into new file named `2022-02-10.txt`, or preferably, into suitable `.KML` file.

Comment: every event is in separated line so you can use Python to read line by line and use regext to find text after `TS:` and after `GPS:`

Comment: (1) Do all 100,000 records have the same ‘‘datestamp’’ (“2022-02-10”)?  If not, expand your example to show multiple different dates … (2) … and explain more clearly what output you want.  (3) For example, for the three records you have shown, what two things do you want to extract?  (4) What is a “suitable .KML file”?  (5) *Show and describe* the output you want. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every event is in separated line so you can read line by line and use `regex` to find text after `TS:` and after `GPS:` - and then you can use `TS` as filename and write in `append mode`

---

Minimal working example.

I use `io` with `text` only to simulate file in memory but you should use `open()`

```py
text = '''./production.log.109.gz:I, [2022-02-10T10:00:59.703529 #25190]  INFO -- : #<Event::TeltonikaServer:3ffcbe931d90>:357544377733734 TS: 2022-02-10 10:00:35 +0000, GPS: 52.1773033,20.8162, SAT: 17, KM/H: 0, V: 26343
./production.log.109.gz:I, [2022-02-10T10:01:13.939349 #25190]  INFO -- : #<Event::TeltonikaServer:3ffcbe931d90>:357544377733734 TS: 2022-02-10 10:00:40 +0000, GPS: 52.1773033,20.8162, SAT: 17, KM/H: 0, V: 26352
./production.log.109.gz:I, [2022-02-10T10:10:44.757308 #25190]  INFO -- : #<Event::TeltonikaServer:3ffcbe931d90>:357544377733734 TS: 2022-02-10 10:10:40 +0000, GPS: 52.1773033,20.8162, SAT: 18, KM/H: 0, V: 25924
'''

import io
import re

# open file for reading
#file_in = open("filename.log")
file_in = io.StringIO(text)

# read line by line
for line in file_in:

    # find values
    ts  = re.findall('TS: ([^ ]*) ', line)[0]
    gps = re.findall('GPS: ([^ ]*), ', line)[0]
    val = gps.split(',')
    gps = f'{val[1]},{val[0]}'
    
    print('TS:', ts, '| GPS:', gps)
    
    # open file for writing in `append mode`
    with open(f'{ts}.txt', 'a') as file_out:
        # write in new line
        file_out.write(gps + '\n')
```

Result:

```
TS: 2022-02-10 | GPS: 20.8162,52.1773033
TS: 2022-02-10 | GPS: 20.8162,52.1773033
TS: 2022-02-10 | GPS: 20.8162,52.1773033
```

---

`KML` is more complex format (which uses `XML` structure) and I will not try to write it.
But there are Python module to write in `KML` - ie. [simplekml](https://simplekml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted.html#quick-example)

It may not have function to append to file so first it may need to get all values GPS, group by data and later create KML for every group and save all point at once.

---

**EDIT:**

```
text = '''./production.log.109.gz:I, [2022-02-10T10:00:59.703529 #25190]  INFO -- : #<Event::TeltonikaServer:3ffcbe931d90>:357544377733734 TS: 2022-02-10 10:00:35 +0000, GPS: 52.1773033,20.8162, SAT: 17, KM/H: 0, V: 26343
./production.log.109.gz:I, [2022-02-10T10:01:13.939349 #25190]  INFO -- : #<Event::TeltonikaServer:3ffcbe931d90>:357544377733734 TS: 2022-02-10 10:00:40 +0000, GPS: 52.1773033,20.8162, SAT: 17, KM/H: 0, V: 26352
./production.log.109.gz:I, [2022-02-10T10:10:44.757308 #25190]  INFO -- : #<Event::TeltonikaServer:3ffcbe931d90>:357544377733734 TS: 2022-02-10 10:10:40 +0000, GPS: 52.1773033,20.8162, SAT: 18, KM/H: 0, V: 25924
'''

import io
import re
import simplekml

#f = open("filename.log")
f = io.StringIO(text)

# -----------------------

groups = {}

for line in f:
    ts  = re.findall('TS: ([^ ]*) ', line)[0]
    gps = re.findall('GPS: ([^ ]*), ', line)[0]
    val = gps.split(',')
    gps = [val[1],val[0]]
    
    print('TS:', ts, '| GPS:', gps)
    
    if ts not in groups:
        groups[ts] = []
        
    groups[ts].append(gps)
    
#----------------------------------------
    
for name, values in groups.items():
    print('name:', name)
    
    kml = simplekml.Kml()
    
    for gps in values:
        kml.newpoint(coords=[gps])
        
    # --- after loop ---
    kml.save(f"{name}.kml")
```

Comment: Seems to work like i wanted to after slight modification (i wanted just GPS data, no text, so it wasn't much coding, more like styling), but there is one BUT. For no real reason program stops at 12-02-2022, while datas are from 10-02 up to 17-03.

Comment: Okay, it tends to do more after just launching program on and on, but i can automate it with crone. Will let you know if i managed to put this into existing KML using your code.
Thank you very much !

Comment: Okay, is there any way to "switch" numbers order?

Comment: KML file is reading those as longtitude, atitude, while my datas are atitude, longtitude, making my pathmark to show up in Saudi Arabia, not Europe :O

Comment: you get  `val = gps.split(',')` and later put as `val[1],val[0]`. I add this to code

Comment: as for adding to existing file: it seems `simplekml` can't read `kml` and it would need to use different module. It seems [fastkml](https://fastkml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage_guide.html#read-a-kml-file-string) can read so it would need to rewrite all with `fastkml`

Answer (score 0):

So i changed code completely after studying Python for few days.

Basically:

- read file data.log
- extract GPS & TimeStamp
- Put GPS into Associtive Array
- Listed Array into filed based on their TS into files (e.g. TS.txt)
- Added header and footer with one for loop

And that's all, i've made it like i wanted. Thanks everyone for helping.